# nuxtjs/router use runtime config client side

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables, nuxt.js

we are using `nuxt 2.14.12` and `@nuxtjs/router 1.5.0`
we are trying to use runtime config to make some HTTP request client side.

here is our `router.js`

```
export async function createRouter(ssrContext, createDefaultRouter) {

[...]

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${config.public.apiBaseUrl}/myslug`)
  } catch (e) { }

[...]

}
```

here is the config file

```
[...]

  const apiBaseUrl = `${process.env.NUXT_ENV_MY_API_URL || 'http://my-dev-domain.com'}`

[...]

export default {
    apiBaseUrl,
  },
  private: {
    apiBaseUrl,
  },

[...]
```

here is our `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {

[...]

  publicRuntimeConfig: config.public,
  privateRuntimeConfig: config.private,

[...]

  buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/router', { keepDefaultRouter: true }],
  ],

[...]

  router: {
    linkActiveClass: 'current-menu-item'
  },
[...]
}
```

we use `nuxt build` in our CI and later at runtime we use `nuxt start`

at runtime, despite on server side the env variable `NUXT_ENV_MY_API_URL` is correctly set, on the client site the variable looks hardcoded (I think webpack replace it) and we get the value present on build time (`http://my-dev-domain.com`)

is there a way to use the runtime config on the client side?

thank you